# I cannot seem to find a package I installed a while ago (jupyterthemes)

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Alright, so I've installed [jupyter themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) a while ago. In the mean time, I reinstalled python and anaconda (switched to miniconda) environment multiple times. Now, when I launch a jupyter notebook, I still get the style from jupyter themes. However, when I enter

```
jt -r
```

in the command line, I get:

```
'jt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

And it's true, when I execute `pip list` the package jupyterthemes isn't there. I also looked into my conda environments and couldn't seem to find it. How do I successfully remove it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows. What I did was "pip install" the library again, and returned everything to default. Couldn't possibly find where the package is hidden